# Python: what encoding does "print" use?

Tags: python, string, unicode

I have the following string:

```
u'Il mare \xe8 bello'
```

If I `print` it, it appears correctly:

```
Il mare è bello
```

But when I pass it to a library ([tweepy](http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v3.2.0/)), I get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe8' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried to convert it with str, unicode, codecs, encode and decode, but I always get the same error. Any idea?

Comment: The problem is not with `print`, but that `tweepy` doesn't accept Unicode strings.

Comment: Why do you think the error message is related to `print` statement? Show the complete traceback.

Answer (score 2):

It should be the default encoding, unless you are changing it -

`sys.getdefaultencoding()`

Comment: `print` does not use `sys.getdefaultencoding()` encoding unless `sys.stdout.encoding is None`. Though it is likely that the error message refers to it i.e., the title and the error message might be unrelated unless the output is redirected when the code with `tweepy` is run.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you asking about print when you actually have a problem with tweepy? And why are you not showing us your code trying to use tweepy? Anyway, you should be able to encode it like this:

```
u'Il mare \xe8 bello'.encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

The default encoding on Python2 is Ascii, on Python3, it is UTF8.